# Intellij takes for ever (>30 seconds) before even attempting to run/debug a main

Tags: intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ under Windows/Linux and Mac (13- 14 and 14.1) every time I launch the Main it takes a very long time (> 20 seconds) being completely idle before *starting* to compile or launch the program.

The same 1 minute block happens just *editing* the run configuration: it appears white for the exact period before showing the running/debug configuration.

This appear independend of the OS and the speed of the CPU/Disk I'm using, so I'm hoping it's just some "timeout" happening somewhere.

Unit tests which are doing something similar are taking a bit but not so much, and if I launch the same main from Eclipse it starts instantly.

Is there something I'm missing in configuration of IntelliJ / Run or in setup of IntelliJ to avoid this long block?

NOTE: The project has some multiple modules in it separating the spray routing in a module, the datamodel (mongodb) in another, data definition in a third one and having multiple sbt script, could it be possible that this time is related to some sbt activities or inconsistencies in dependencies?

Comment: Report a bug. Or do you think that the 20 second delay is some kind of feature, which you can switch off?

Comment: Before filing a bug yes I wanted to ask if anybody else using intellij with spray is experiencing something similar with medium big sized projects...

Comment: Please capture a CPU snapshot as described in https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-192 and attach it to your bug report. Regardless of how exactly your project is set up, this kind of delay is a bug.